# Iterating through dataframes as a table in a list on R

Tags: r, dataframe, loops

I am kinda new to R and I have been working with dataframes as well as the loop (for) function is R. This time, I tried to append 3 dataframes, of which are made out of 3 columns, into a list. This is one of the dataframes that I append to the list.

[image]

As seen above, this dataframes contains 3 columns, but it is just 1 table.

However, as I append it to the list, the dataframes are separated as 9 different dataframes.

[image]

I want to iterate through list as 3 dataframes, not 9. How can I do this? I have tried this code to no avail:

```
df
plc_korpus_list <- list()

plc_korpus_list <- c(plc_korpus_list, df))

for (i in plc_korpus_list){
    print(i)
  }
```

How can I iterate through the dataframes in the list, as three separate tables?

I tried I have tried the for loops, I expected the i to retrieve each table, not just column. How can I get only the table? I'd like to rbind them at the end.

Thank you. Sorry if my explanation is unclear.

Comment: Hi, let me understand correctly, so you have 3 different dataframes with 3 columns and what do you want to achieve? what is final output? just printing out column names or data frame names via for loop? give me your calculation what you want to do with dataframes

Comment: It's `c(plc_korpus_list, df)` that breaks your frame. It's better to avoid growing objects, but if you really need to append, use `c(plc_korpus_list, list(df))`

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand your question. Maybe this helps you. It also allows you to manipulate your `df`'s without using a `for` loop.

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- tibble(
  a = 1:10,
  b = LETTERS[1:10]
)

df2 <- tibble(
  a = 11:20,
  b = LETTERS[11:20]
)

df3 <- tibble(
  a = 21:30,
  b = letters[1:10], 
  c = rnorm(10, 0, 1)
)

dflist <- list(df1, df2, df3)

xx <- tibble(
  id = 1:length(dflist),
  v = dflist
)

## mutate if you want; uunest if you want
xx %>% 
  mutate(v = map(.x = v, .f = \(x) 
                 x %>% mutate(
                   d = paste("d", a, b, sep = ""), 
                   rn = row_number()
                   )
                 )) %>% 
  unnest(v)
```

Answer (score 0):

If `l1` and `l2` are both `list`s, the `c()` function will *append* the items in `l2` to `l1`, i.e., you get a single list:

```
> c(list(A = 1, B = "x"), list(C = 2, D = "y"))
$A
[1] 1

$B
[1] "x"

$C
[1] 2

$D
[1] "y"
```

As you probably know, `data.frame`s are `lists`s (with a few restrictions), so if you `c()` two `data.frame`s, you'll get a list with all columns of the two `data.frame`s:

```
> df1 <- data.frame(X = LETTERS[1:3], Y = 1:3, Z = 4:6)
> df2 <- data.frame(X = LETTERS[4:6], Y = 1:3, Z = 4:6)
> c(df1, df2)

$X
[1] "A" "B" "C"

$Y
[1] 1 2 3

$Z
[1] 4 5 6

$X
[1] "D" "E" "F"

$Y
[1] 1 2 3

$Z
[1] 4 5 6
```

In order to get a `list` of `list`s, you must use the `list()` function to create a new `list`, in which each item is itself a list:

```
> list(df1, df2)
[[1]]
  X Y Z
1 A 1 4
2 B 2 5
3 C 3 6

[[2]]
  X Y Z
1 D 1 4
2 E 2 5
3 F 3 6
```

Comment: This was insightful, thank you! Its also nice to note margusl's comments about using list(df) when iterating it through loop :)